# flatpickr: disable dates previously picked

Tags: calendar, calculator, flatpickr

I am working on a visa calculator and want the user to be able to pick multiple trips (picking entry and exit dates in separate fields) that will be added. I am only using JS.
When creating a new trip, two input fields open up, that get their own individual ids. When showing the calendar, I want to disable all previously picked dates (and dates in between of course). How can I dynamically achieve that?

newFpEntry = flatpickr(`#entryDate${entryDateNum}`,
              {maxDate: new Date(entryDate).fp_incr(timeFrameValueCalendar),
              disable: [
                     ???
                      ]
                    });

Hope I described my problem well. I appreciate any idea!

Answer (score 1):

So, I figured something out.

> 1. I pushed each new date pair (entry and exit) in form of an object into an array (previously defined), using flatpickr's syntax, 
>      assigning the key *from:* to the value *newEntryDate* and the key *to:* to the value *newExitDate*
>
>    > `allBlockedDates.push({from: newEntryDate, to: newExitDate});`
> 2. I inserted the array into flatpickr
>
>    > `` newFpEntry = flatpickr(`#entryDate${entryDateNum}`,
>    >             {
>    >              disable: allBlockedDates
>    >             }); ``

Hope this might be helpful for anyone else struggling with a similar problem.